Is there an open source PySide project with a UI layout framework similar to Cytoscape?
Excuse me, is there an open source PySide project with a UI layout framework similar to Cytoscape?
This UI layout has the following characteristics:

The pane can float.
The pane can be pulled (enlarged/reduced).
The pane can be maximized/minimized.


